# Your favorite command-line tools to use remotely on Windows

Tags: windows, command-line, remote

I suppose many of us use their windows machine remotely for example with ssh for windows. What are you favorite command-line tools besides bundled with Windows and maybe besides the ones from sysinternals (that can be considered Microsoft originated after they bought sysinternals)

Comment: This should be a community wiki due to the nature of the question.

Answer (score 2):

You mean like PowerShell? I find myself running powershell even in a command prompt window so that I can do piping of objects from one command to another, and hooking into the register, certificates, environment variables, SQL Server, Exchange, AD, etc... too

And dtexec, and sqlcmd?

Comment: Impressive, but I meant classic console applications (can be executed from cmd.exe) originated from anywhere other than Microsoft

Comment: Edited the post, to indicate that even running cmd, I may then run powershell.

Comment: +1 for the PS, but as I see from the search I need extra steps to make it work remotely

Answer (score 2):

[Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/) for any unix tool you like.   :)

Answer (score 1):

PSExec or shutdown on remote machines is always fun, as was the net send command in a school environment.

Answer (score 0):

I recall using [Dameware NT Utilities](http://www.dameware.com/) heavily in college.